# Using Local Storage to Store and Display multiple Answers

Tags: javascript, string, html, button, local-storage

I'm working on a webpage where i'm trying to display a question, and have viewers submit an answer, which appears on another page. Currently, only the most recent answer is shown on the answer page. I'm not sure how to write my function so that it stores and displays all responses. (I'm new to javascript) Thanks!

```
    <div id=q2 class="question gr">
         What is good design?
   <input id="q2input" type="text" > 

   <div class="buttons"> <button onclick="functionTwo()"          
   class="sbuttons">Submit</button>

                <!-- View Answers Button -->  
    <button id="ViewAnswers2" class="vabuttons" >View Answers</button>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("ViewAnswers2").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "WhatIsGoodDesign.html";
    };
    </script>
       </div>

   <script>
   function functionTwo(){
       var input = document.getElementById("q2input").value;
       console.log(input);
       localStorage.setItem("question2", input);
       window.location.href = "WhatIsGoodDesign.html";
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array instead. Currently, all you are doing is overwriting the current value in the `question2` answer slot every time. Arrays are ways to store multiple data values into one variable

```
function functionTwo() {
  var input = document.getElementById("q2input").value;
  var answers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("question2answers")) || []; 
  //Not too sure about the || [];
  answers.push(input);
  localStorage.setItem("question2answers", JSON.stringify(answers));
  window.location.href = "WhatIsGoodDesign.html";
}
```

You cannot directly put an array into LocalStorage, so you have to pass it in and out as a JSON object. JSON.stringify() will turn it into a string that you can pass into LocalStorage, while JSON.parse() will translate that string back into an array.

Comment: I tried this and now no responses appear on the next page. Could I have to change something with the code I have on the "WhatIsGoodDesign.html" page?       <script>
       var gooddesign = localStorage.getItem("question2answer" + (parseInt(localStorage.getItem("question2Answers")) - 1).toString())
       console.log(gooddesign);
       document.getElementById("q2").innerHTML = gooddesign;
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

You currently overwrite the key `question2` with the new answer each time. If you want a list of the the last answers. You would have to do something along the lines of:

```
function functionTwo(){
   var input = document.getElementById("q2input").value;
   var numAnswers = localStorage.getItem("question2numAnswers") || 0;
   localStorage.setItem("question2answer" + numAnswers.toString(), input);
   localStorage.setItem("question2numAnswers", numAnswers + 1);
   window.location.href = "WhatIsGoodDesign.html";
}
```

This way you keep track of the number of answers with `question2numAnswers` and each answer with `question2answer#` and you can loop through the answers on your next page by going from 0 to question2numAnswers that you store.

Comment: When I use this code and type and submit an answer, it doesn't show up on the next page

Comment: You'll have to edit the next page to use `localStorage.getItem("question2answer" + (parseInt(localSotrage.getItem("question2numAnswers")) - 1).toString())` to get the latest answer (sorry that's all mashed up but essentially your using numAnswers to index your question2answer# list)

Comment: I changed the script on the next page to:    <script>
       var gooddesign = localStorage.getItem("question2answer" + (parseInt(localStorage.getItem("question2numAnswers")) - 1).toString())
       console.log(gooddesign);
       document.getElementById("q2").innerHTML = gooddesign;
    </script>   am I still missing something? Nothing comes up on the page now